# What does the word 'Fakhert' mean in yiddish?

Tags: language, yiddish

It pops up in a bunch of shiurim but I can't seem to find a definition online.

Comment: It means, "to the contrary," or, "the opposite is true".

Comment: thanks! @pcoz answer this question with this and I'll mark it as answered

Comment: It is essentially the yiddish equivalent of *aderaba*

Comment: @Dov And amusingly, *aderaba* in Yiddish also means "certainly, by all means"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fakehrt* generally means "to the contrary," or, "the opposite is true".

*Punkt fakehrt* means the "exact opposite is true".

A *fakehrte sevara* means "an opposite way of reasoning."

Comment: It's usually written פארקערט in Yiddish, with a resh, but the r sound often gets swallowed. It literally means "opposite, reverse".